# How do I suppress warnings in NAnt when using the solution task?

Tags: nant, compiler-warnings, .net-1.1

We have a .NET 1.1 solution that we are compiling using NAnt with a "solution" task.

One of the projects throws multiple warnings for missing XML comments. I know which warnings I need to suppress (from http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/177026-suppress-missing-xml-comment-warning-during-compile), but I can't see how. The csc task has a  configuration element that can be used for this, but I can't see an equivalent for solution.

Is this even possible? How can I do it?

Comment: If you dont have many projects why bother making the xml documentation files at all? Its only making them that causes the error and do you use them? Probably not. Go into the project settings build tab and uncheck xml documentation files, still think you must need msbee for 1.1 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to prefer running an exec task for msbuild.  This will suppress all warnings:

```
<exec program="${msbuild_exe_path}">
   <arg line='"${solution_path}"' />
   <arg line="/property:WarningLevel=0" />
   <!-- SNIP  -->           
</exec>
```

More info on warning level settings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7.aspx

Getting msbuild to work on .net 1.1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2004/11/29/271748.aspx

Comment: @James Woolfenden: Actually read the answer.  The snip demonstrated syntax, the link illustrated all the available warning level settings.  Implementation details are left up to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Replace NAnt's [`<solution>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/solution.html) task by NAntContrib's [`<msbuild>`](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/msbuild.html) task. You can pass solution files to MSBuild as well as project files and you can pass [MSBuild properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) like `WarningLevel` then. Find an example [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/geekusconlivus/archive/2007/02/03/105375.aspx).

Comment: I was under the impression that .NET 1.1 was not supported by MSBuild. The only references I can find would involve converting all our code to a later version of .NET in order to use MSBuild EE.

Comment: adam.kuyrkendall's answer should work as well. While the `<msbuild>` task IMHO is more comfortable, the `<exec>` task doesn't require NAntContrib. The .NET 1.1 conversion looks promising.